# Where can I find all list of style properties supported by react native?

Tags: react-native

Where can I get a list of the style properties supported by React Native for each type of component?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Here's a cheatsheet:

- [React Native Styling Cheat Sheet](https://github.com/vhpoet/react-native-styling-cheat-sheet)

The supported styles are in the official documentation for each component. Here are the links for `View` and `Text` components:

- `View` : https://reactnative.dev/docs/view#style
- `Text`: https://reactnative.dev/docs/text#style

Note that where it says *View Style Props...* on the top of styles for Text, it means it also supports (most of) the styles that `View` supports.

Comment: It's not always there, e. g. [TouchableHighlight](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablehighlight.html#style) is empty.

Comment: This answer seems outdated as there is absolutely nothing in the documentation anymore (in the provided link anyway). The "view style prop" page (https://reactnative.dev/docs/text-style-props) does not tell anything about inherited style properties.

Comment: Moreover, as of RN 0.69.1 there are also "Layout Properties" (e.g. flex) that aren't always listed.

Answer (score 15):

I have extracted a list of valid styles from react native logs.

Below collection help me alot during regular work.

```
[
  "alignContent",
  "alignItems",
  "alignSelf",
  "aspectRatio",
  "backfaceVisibility",
  "backgroundColor",
  "borderBottomColor",
  "borderBottomLeftRadius",
  "borderBottomRightRadius",
  "borderBottomWidth",
  "borderColor",
  "borderLeftColor",
  "borderLeftWidth",
  "borderRadius",
  "borderRightColor",
  "borderRightWidth",
  "borderStyle",
  "borderTopColor",
  "borderTopLeftRadius",
  "borderTopRightRadius",
  "borderTopWidth",
  "borderWidth",
  "bottom",
  "color",
  "decomposedMatrix",
  "direction",
  "display",
  "elevation",
  "flex",
  "flexBasis",
  "flexDirection",
  "flexGrow",
  "flexShrink",
  "flexWrap",
  "fontFamily",
  "fontSize",
  "fontStyle",
  "fontVariant",
  "fontWeight",
  "height",
  "includeFontPadding",
  "justifyContent",
  "left",
  "letterSpacing",
  "lineHeight",
  "margin",
  "marginBottom",
  "marginHorizontal",
  "marginLeft",
  "marginRight",
  "marginTop",
  "marginVertical",
  "maxHeight",
  "maxWidth",
  "minHeight",
  "minWidth",
  "opacity",
  "overflow",
  "overlayColor",
  "padding",
  "paddingBottom",
  "paddingHorizontal",
  "paddingLeft",
  "paddingRight",
  "paddingTop",
  "paddingVertical",
  "position",
  "resizeMode",
  "right",
  "rotation",
  "scaleX",
  "scaleY",
  "shadowColor",
  "shadowOffset",
  "shadowOpacity",
  "shadowRadius",
  "textAlign",
  "textAlignVertical",
  "textDecorationColor",
  "textDecorationLine",
  "textDecorationStyle",
  "textShadowColor",
  "textShadowOffset",
  "textShadowRadius",
  "tintColor",
  "top",
  "transform",
  "transformMatrix",
  "translateX",
  "translateY",
  "width",
  "writingDirection",
  "zIndex"
]
```

Implementation details are here:
https://github.com/vhpoet/react-native-styling-cheat-sheet/blob/master/README.md

Comment: -1; it's not clear where this list came from (so we can't even be confident that it's correct), plus there's no indication of how to update it for future releases, plus this answer is kind of misleading to newbies since it fails to note that different style rules are applicable to different components.

Comment: @MarkAmery As i have clearly mentioned that i got the list from the logs, everybody can find these valid style properties.
Set of the rules can be found here:
https://github.com/vhpoet/react-native-styling-cheat-sheet/blob/master/README.md

Comment: *What* logs? Maybe I'm missing something obvious, but I have no idea what you mean.