# List of styling properties in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

React native have its own set of supported CSS properties. Do we have a list of supported properties with an example ?

For example:

**JustifyContent** support one of the following *"flex-start", "flex-end", "center", "space-between", "space-around"*

Comment: All what you need is explained here https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/style.html. Navigate through each page and you'll find all the supported properties with examples.

Comment: Have a look on this suggestion, you could get quick help. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46428185/3741769

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is duplicated and already have an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39021886/where-can-i-find-all-list-of-style-properties-supported-by-react-native).

You can go to https://github.com/vhpoet/react-native-styling-cheat-sheet. It's a list of supported style in React native.